# How to calculate volume in R5

Tags: real-analysis

Find the volume of $\Omega=\{(x,y,z,u,v):x^2+y^2+z^2+u^2+v^2)<=1\}$.

I have no idea what to do.

Comment: What's "R5" ? Where, how and when does the "calculate volume" thingy kick in? What've you done so far, what's your own effort...?

Comment: sorry, copy-paste error...

Comment: Nice @user118443. But as this is an advanced calculus question I bet you *must* have some ideas...I don't know, multiple integrals or stuff. I think it is a good idea to write down some.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the volume of a sphere, you can integrate like this using polar substitution:
$$\underset{x^2+y^2+z^2+u^2+v^2\leq1}{\int\!\!\!\int\!\!\!\int\!\!\!\int\!\!\!\int}\!\!\!\!\!\!1\ d(x,y,z,u,v)=\iint\limits_{u^2+v^2\leq1}\left(\ \iiint\limits_{x^2+y^2+z^2\leq1-u^2+v^2}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!1\ d(x,y,z)\right)d(u,v)=\\\iint\limits_{u^2+v^2\leq1}\!\!\frac43\pi\left(\sqrt{1-u^2-v^2}\right)^3\ d(u,v)=\iint\limits_{0\leq r\leq1\ \land\ 0\leq\varphi\leq2\pi}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\frac43\pi\left(\sqrt{1-r^2}\right)^3\cdot r\ d(r,\varphi)=\\\frac23\pi\cdot2\pi\int\limits_{0\leq r\leq1}2r(1-r^2)^\frac32\ dr=\frac43\pi^2\left[-\frac25(1-r^2)^\frac52\right]_0^1=\frac43\pi^2\cdot\frac25=\frac8{15}\pi^2$$

Comment: No, everything's fine...+1

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is to generalize polar coordinates.

You can check out any existing online description about a hypersphere (n-ball volume):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball